# displaying numbers with legend on pie chart - Tkinter, Pyplot, Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pie-chart

I am developing a application using Tkinter for the interface, and then using pyplot from matplotlib to create a pie chart.

I have successfuly been able to display the data on a pie chart without a legend, such that the percentages are shown. Below is the relevant source code extract.

```
labels = ["Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Kiwis", "Grapes", "Pears"]
values = [0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]

 # now to get the total number of failed in each section
actualFigure = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
actualFigure.suptitle("Fruit Stats", fontsize = 22)

#explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
# as explode needs to contain numerical values for each "slice" of the pie chart (i.e. every group needs to have an associated explode value)
explode = list()
for k in labels:
    explode.append(0.1)

pie= plt.pie(values, labels=labels, explode = explode, shadow=True)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(actualFigure, self)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.show()
```

I have also been able to display the same pie chart, with the legend but without the numerical values:

```
labels = ["Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Kiwis", "Grapes", "Pears"]
values = [0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]

 # now to get the total number of failed in each section
actualFigure = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
actualFigure.suptitle("Fruit Stats", fontsize = 22)

#explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
# as explode needs to contain numerical values for each "slice" of the pie chart (i.e. every group needs to have an associated explode value)
explode = list()
for k in labels:
    explode.append(0.1)

pie, text= plt.pie(values, labels=labels, explode = explode, shadow=True)
plt.legend(pie, labels, loc = "upper corner")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(actualFigure, self)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.show()
```

However, I am unable to display both the legend and the numerical values on the pie chart, at the same time.

If I add "autopct='%1.1f%%'" field into the pie, text = plt.pie(...) line I get the following error:

"pie, text= plt.pie(values, labels=labels, explode = explode, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add `autopct` to the [pie function](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie), the returned format changes resulting in your `too many values to unpack` message being displayed. The following should work:

```
pie = plt.pie(values, labels=labels, explode=explode, shadow=True, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.legend(pie[0], labels, loc="upper corner")
```

Giving you the following output:

[image: sample output]

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Martin.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation,

> If *autopct* is not none, pie returns the tuple (*patches*, *texts*, *autotexts*).

Hence you can make the above work by using the following line:

```
pie, texts, autotexts = plt.pie(values, labels=labels, explode=explode, shadow=True, autopct='%1.1f%%')
```